# How do I get max value from group?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Trying to get max value from group with other columns. I have researched examples online but doesn't seem to work in my query. COL1 is unique in my table. Trying to get duplicate rows with MAX(COL1).

```
SELECT COL1,
        COL2, COL3,
        cnt, max(COL1)
FROM   (SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL2, COL3  ORDER BY COL1 desc) AS cnt
        FROM   TABLE_1 
        where ( COL2 is not null and COL3 is not null) e

    Here is sample data
    -------------------
        COL1   COL2   COL3  
        27     2222   2224   
        28     2222   2224   
        30     2222   2224   
        48     5552   8888   
        50     5552   8888   

expected result
--------------------------

    COL1   COL2   COL3  cnt  MAX(COL1)
    30     2222   2224   1    30
    28     2222   2224   2    30
    27     2222   2224   3    30
    50     5552   8888   1    50
    48     5552   8888   2    50
```

Comment: Hard to understand what you are trying to do here without sample data and expected results.

Comment: If it's unique, how can there be duplicates? Those are opposites.

Comment: Yeah I have no idea what you're trying to ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this works for you:

```
select COL1, COL2, COL3,
    row_number() over(partition by COL2, COL3 order by COL1 desc) as cnt,
    max(COL1) over(partition by COL2, COL3) as MAXCOL1
from table1
where COL2 is not null and COL3 is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DENSE_RANK` to get ranking within a partition, for e.g.

```
SELECT COL2, COL3, COL1, cnt
FROM
    (SELECT *,
     DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY COL2, COL3 ORDER BY COL1 DESC) AS cnt
     FROM TABLE_1
     WHERE COL2 IS NOT NULL AND COL3 IS NOT NULL)
WHERE cnt = 1
```